# How to validate a REST Assured request across multiple java methods?

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

I am writing REST Assured tests using Cucumber.

Here is my feature file:

> Given I want to GET a client
>
> When I request a client
>
> Then the status code is "theStatusCode"
>
> And the id returned is "expectedClientId"

The below method is called within the Step Definition of the ***"And"*** in my feature file

```
public void validateResponseBody(String expectedClientId){
    RestAssured.given()
    .when()
    .get(completeURL)
    .then()
    .statusCode(Integer.parseInt(theStatusCode))
    .and()
    .body("Client.Id", equalTo(expectedClientId));
}
```

This method currently works, but how do I split the validation?

I.e. how can I break this up to validate the Status Code in one method, & validate the Client Id in another method without having to send the request twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save response to variable:

```
public void validate() {
    ValidatableResponse response = RestAssured.given()
        .when()
        .get(completeURL)
        .then();

    validateStatusCode(response, statusCode);
    validateResponseBody(response, expectedClientId);
}

public void validateStatusCode(ValidatableResponse response, String statusCode) {
    response
        .statusCode(Integer.parseInt(theStatusCode));
}

public void validateResponseBody(ValidatableResponse response, String expectedClientId) {
    response
        .body("Client.Id", equalTo(expectedClientId));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this really helps. I understand which step definition should call _validateStatusCode_ and _validateResponseBody_ but which step should execute **validate**? Should I add a new _Then_ step?

Answer (score 0):

```
I suggest to make changes in Feature File. 
New File should be given below. You don't need a when statement here.
Scenario: I want to GET a client  
Given I request a client  
Then the status code is "theStatusCode"  
And the id returned is "expectedClientId"  

@Given("I request a client$")  
public void validate() 
{ 
ValidatableResponse validatableResponse = RestAssured.given()
        .when()
        .get(completeURL)
        .then();
}  
@Then("the status code is \"([^\"]*)\"$") 
public void validateStatusCode(String statusCode) 
{ 
validatableResponse.assertThat().statusCode(Integer.parseInt(theStatusCode));
} 

@And("the id returned is \"([^\"]*)\"$") 
public void validateClientId(String expectedClientId)
{
validatableResponse.assertThat().body("Client.Id", equalTo(expectedClientId));
}
```